# Div can't be aligned properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

let's take a quick look at http://tadbirnc.ir/ with less than 800px browser's width, you'll find out the logo doesn't fit the right place, if you inspect the container div, you can see everything is right (i think) and I don't know why there is a gap at the right side of the logo.
I have to correct this using jQuery by overwriting some css rules.

here is the html code of this part :

```html
<div class="header-mobile"></div>
<div class="container header-items">
  <div style="max-width: 200px;" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/skin/default/images/theme/logo.png" id="img-logo" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 page-rev-align page-rev-float">Blah Blah Blah</div>
</div>
```

the problem is that The div with class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" doesn't align to right.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please check it my answer

Comment: If I remove the `max-width: 200px;` like mentioned in one of the answers, the logo appears on the right side. Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the hard-set `max-width:200px;` on the element. You are going to need to target the element with a CSS media query and set the correct width for smaller screen sizes.

Good luck out there!

Comment: no success after removing "max-width" property, because the problem is about it's containers

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
.logo
{
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8t6rdd3e/)

Comment: No luck with this one too, you can test it I the website, the problem is caused buy parent divs of .logo

Answer (score 0):

please add `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"`

add this css

```
 max-width: 200px;
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
```